# Create a matrix without any format (unstructured) in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, matrix, dynamic

I have a question about creating a new dynamic matrix with some requirements.

I already know how to create a matrix 2D array in C by using one or two pointer(s0). However, the requirements are that I need to create a matrix without any format. 
The requirement: Create a matrix like the one below:

```
Matrix A = 
1 2 3
5 5    7
2   5  5
```

The spaces have no element and A03,A12,A21 = NULL

Comment: You could use a matrix of pointers, and use `NULL` for the elements that have no value.

Comment: What does the 'without any format' requirement mean?  How are you going to set the values in different elements of the matrix?  How do you specify the size of the matrix?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209496/discussion-between-barmar-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: Thank you so much,  all of you. I've got a hint to do my stuff.